# Security hole in LDAP configuration of serverguide?

Tags: 12.04, server, ldap

I'm just setting up a new openLDAP server for user authentification and stumbled over the access control statements in the serverguide. In especially:

access to *
   by self write
   ...

As the access to the "uidNumber" attribute isn't prohibited by a previous statement, this allows any user with an LDAP account to change their "uidNumber" to 0 (root) and login using their default credentials and become root (or someone else). At least this is possible on my setup, with this ACLs.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is an excellent question ...but since Ask Ubuntu is not the place for bug reports, **if** it turns out that this is a security hole, then you should [report it as a security bug in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) (against the server guide itself, not against LDAP).